# HiveQL - Linking Three Tables v2

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have three tables, each containing "IDs".  The end result should link an ID_1 in Table A to ID_4 in Table C.  What query would return all the combinations of ID_1 to ID_4?

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A AS (ID_1 STRING, ID_2 STRING );

CREATE TABLE TABLE_B AS (ID_2 STRING, ID_3 STRING );

CREATE TABLE TABLE_C AS (ID_3 STRING, ID_4 STRING );
```

Where ID_2 in Table_A is the same as ID_2 in Table_B.
Where ID_3 in Table_B is the same as ID_3 in Table_C. 
Most relationships between the IDs in each table are 1:1, but there are a few edge cases of many:many.

What query would yield all possibilities of the following combinations?

```
ID_1 to ID_1
ID_1 to ID_4
ID_4 to ID_4
```

A case where `ID_1 to ID_1` would be two distinct ID_1s to one distinct ID_2.

A case where `ID_4 to ID_4` would be one distinct ID_3 to two distinct ID_4s.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I changed the scope of my ask.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax uses explicit joins:

```
SELECT a.ID_1, c.ID_4
FROM TABLE_A a JOIN
     TABLE_B b
     ON a.ID_2 = b.ID_2 JOIN
     TABLE_C c
     ON b.ID_3 = c.ID_3;
```

That said, this is functionally equivalent to your query.

Comment: (The prefix # corresponds to the ID_#)
`TABLE_A 
1AA -> 2AA
1BB -> 2AA`

`TABLE_B
2AA -> 3AA
2AA -> 3BB`

`TABLE_C
3AA -> 4AA
3AA -> 4BB
3BB -> 4AA
3BB -> 4CC`

In TABLE_C, 3AA and 3BB are connected to the same ID, 4AA.  Would this example be covered?  What would catch all possible permutations?

Comment: Sorry, the above is an example.